# How to repent from all the sins a person has comitted?

Tags: sin, shirk, tawba

Can you please tell me how can I ask forgiveness from all the sins I have committed, and will shirk also be forgiven by that because I have comitted many shirk when I was between 12 and 13 and I was between puberty in past, will my sins be forgiven without anything because I was young and even if it will forgive my sins I will still repent, I wanted to repent first, but I could not gather sincerity, that's why, I watched videos of mercy of allah and now slowly I am regretting those sins, can you please tell me how can I ask forgiveness? Please Answer? And if I don't have enough sincerity will I be still forgiven? I want to repent but I can't gather enough sincerity, can you please give me a dua for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is already a very good thing to be aware of your sins, it means that you are on the right track.
And Allah is Forgiving and Merciful and He is Most Accepting of repentance, so ask Allah for forgiveness every day and pray and InchaAllah He will forgive you. Also enjoy this blessed month and especially continue afterwards.

May Allah forgive you and guide you to the right path.